# Google Script Explanation

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a Google App Script that is supposed to read each row, see if Column C is marked "true", and if true data validation needs to be removed from all columns in that row. The example code below is not working. I am hoping someone can help educate me as to why.

```js
function skl(){
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var sheet2 = ss.getSheetByName('Savings Register');
    var columnO2 = sheet2.getRange(2, 1, sheet2.getLastRow()-1, 1);
    var oValues2 = columnO2.getValues();
    for (var i = 0; i < oValues2.length; i++) {
        if (oValues2[i][2] == 'TRUE') {
            sheet2.getRange(i + 2, 1, 1, 9).setDataValidation(null);
        }
    }
}
```

If I change it to `if (oValues2[i][0] == 'TRUE')` the code functions when column A is true... but my criteria is column C. Shouldn't this code work with column C being the number 2?

Answer (score 2):

```
var columnO2 = sheet2.getRange(2, 1, sheet2.getLastRow()-1, 1);
```

Your range is essentially specifying "A2:A", therefore column C is not included.

Here's a solution:

```
function myFunction() {

  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Savings Register');
  const data = sheet.getSheetValues(2, 1, sheet.getLastRow()-1, sheet.getLastColumn());

  const targetRows = data.filter(i => i[2] === true);

  for (let row of targetRows) {
    const index = data.findIndex(i => i === row)+2;
    sheet.getRange(index, 1, 1, 9).setDataValidation(null);
  }

}
```

If you have any issues please let me know!

Comment: Thanks for the education/help. Any guesses as to why I get a syntax error when I copy/paste and try to save the script?

Comment: Can you post your error?

Comment: Syntax error: Syntax error. line: 1138 file: Test Accounting Sheet

Comment: Can you post line 1138? I will need more information.

Comment: const targetRows = data.filter(i => i[2] === true);

Comment: You can try changing `true` to `'TRUE'` maybe?

Comment: Same error with 'TRUE' and "TRUE" or any other word in place of true.

Comment: This doesn't make sense, the declaration is syntactically correct. Can you post a larger piece of code in a JSFiddle, etc?

Comment: When I paste into script editor it save just fine.  Perhaps you have an error in another script function